# Run Time Error 91: Object variable or With block not set

Tags: excel, vba

There's no issue with this macro before but suddenly it's giving an error saying "Run Time Error 91: Object variable or With block not set".. Can somebody help me. Thank you

```
Dim zipFile As Variant 
Dim extractFolder As Variant 
Dim test As Object 
zipFile = Range("C1").Value
extractFolder = "<filepath>" 
Set test = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
test.Namespace (extractFolder).CopyHere test.Namespace(zipFile).Items
```

The error is pointing on this line:

```
test.Namespace(extractFolder).CopyHere test.Namespace(zipFile).Items
```

Comment: @FaneDuru I just accidentally put space in the post I updated it now, but there's no space in the actual code. Still the same issue

Comment: Then, check the supplied path/full name variables content. Try `Debug.Print extractFolder & vbcrlf &  zipFile`. Does it show in Immediate Window what to expect?

Comment: Yes, it's showing the correct path/filename in the Immediate window.. But when the debugger goes through this line: ```test.Namespace(extractFolder).CopyHere test.Namespace(zipFile).Items```, the error 91 shows up @FaneDuru

Comment: I remember now that using late binding it may be a problem with `test` object creation. it works well as you try using early binding (adding a reference to 'Microsoft Shell control and something else'... I think, I have a piece of code solving it for early binding, too. I remember something about double parenthesis...

Comment: Does it work if you hard-code the paths in the last line?

Comment: It works in my local, but on remote desktop it is the same error.. The issue started when the remote has updated.. can it be the possible cause? @TimWilliams

Comment: Are you certain the paths are valid on the problem PC?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using:

```
test.Namespace((extractFolder)).CopyHere test.Namespace((zipFile)).Items
```

It should work. It will also work using:

```
test.NameSpace("" & extractFolder & "").CopyHere test.NameSpace("" & zipFile & "").items
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's still the same issue.. it's highlighted here specifically: ```test.Namespace((extractFolder)).CopyHere```

Comment: @Xev It is strange. It should work if the path is correct. Please, try identifying which part of the code does return the error. `Dim extFold as Object` `Set extFold = test.Namespace((extractFolder))`, followed by `Dim zipFItems as Object` `Set zipFItems = test.Namespace((zipFile)).Items`. If the first try raises the error, comment it and see if the second one work as it should.